# Spring-ws with security UnsupportedCallbackException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ws

In spring security for SpringWS I am using

```
<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
    <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="springSecurityHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="springSecurityHandler"
  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

above configuration. But error is javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException

When I debug I found in SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler it is not entering into loop here

```
protected void handleInternal(Callback callback) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    if (callback instanceof PasswordValidationCallback) {
        PasswordValidationCallback validationCallback = (PasswordValidationCallback) callback;
        if (validationCallback.getRequest() instanceof PasswordValidationCallback.PlainTextPasswordRequest) {
            validationCallback.setValidator(new SpringSecurityPlainTextPasswordValidator());
            return;
        }
    }
```

What could be wrong, please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the following callback:

`<bean id="springPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    </bean>`